sending gps data to firebase using sim800l that is connected to a
I used this code which is a combine of two codes to send GPS data to firebase using sim800l model that is connected to arduino uno but it does not connect to the APN even though it connected before I combine the two codes.
#define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM800

#include <TinyGsmClient.h>
#include <ArduinoHttpClient.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TinyGPS++.h>

SoftwareSerial sim800(2, 3);
TinyGPSPlus gps;

const char FIREBASE_HOST[] = "gps";
const String FIREBASE_AUTH = "dC5e*****L";
const String FIREBASE_PATH = "/GPS";
const int SSL_PORT = 443;

char apn[] = "internet"; // Change this to your APN
char user[] = "";
char pass[] = "";

TinyGsm modem(sim800);

TinyGsmClientSecure gsm_client_secure_modem(modem, 0);
HttpClient http_client = HttpClient(gsm_client_secure_modem, FIREBASE_HOST, SSL_PORT);

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("device serial initialize");

  sim800.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("SIM800L serial initialize");

  Serial.println("Initializing modem...");
  modem.restart();
  String modemInfo = modem.getModemInfo();
  Serial.print("Modem: ");
  Serial.println(modemInfo);

  Serial.print(F("Connecting to "));
  Serial.println(apn);

  if (!modem.gprsConnect(apn, user, pass)) {
    Serial.println("GPRS connection failed");
    // You may add retry mechanism or other error handling here
    while (1); // Infinite loop to halt the program
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("GPRS Connected");
  }

  http_client.setHttpResponseTimeout(10 * 1000); // 10 seconds timeout for HTTP responses
  
  Serial.println ("GPS START");
}

void loop()
{
  // Read GPS data
  while (sim800.available())
  {
    gps.encode(sim800.read());
  }
  
  // Example: Sending data to Firebase
  if (millis() - previousMillis > 10000) {
    previousMillis = millis();

    // Sample data to send
    String data = "{\"latitude\": " + String(gps.location.lat(), 6) + ", \"longitude\": " + String(gps.location.lng(), 6) + ", \"speed\": " + String(gps.speed.mph()) + ", \"altitude\": " + String(gps.altitude.feet()) + ", \"satellite_count\": " + String(gps.satellites.value()) + "}";

    // Construct the URL
    String url = FIREBASE_PATH + ".json?auth=" + FIREBASE_AUTH;

    // Send the data
    int statusCode = http_client.post(url, "application/json", data);
    if (statusCode == 200) {
      Serial.println("Firebase POST successful");
    }
    else {
      Serial.print("Firebase POST failed with status code: ");
      Serial.println(statusCode);
    }
  }
}


00:25:00.991 -> device serial initialize
00:25:00.991 -> SIM800L serial initialize
00:25:00.991 -> Initializing modem...
00:25:08.150 -> Modem: SIM800 R14.18
00:25:08.150 -> Connecting to internet
00:26:08.535 -> GPRS connection failed

the first code that I used in the combination is used to send two values to the firebase to test the connection between the sim800l and the server moreover to test the sim800l if it is working and the code worked perfectly it sends the data to the server
#define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM800

#include <TinyGsmClient.h>
#include <ArduinoHttpClient.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial sim800(2, 3);

const char FIREBASE_HOST[] = "gps";
const String FIREBASE_AUTH = "dC5e******L";
const String FIREBASE_PATH = "/GPS";
const int SSL_PORT = 443;

char apn[] = "internet"; // Change this to your APN
char user[] = "";
char pass[] = "";

TinyGsm modem(sim800);

TinyGsmClientSecure gsm_client_secure_modem(modem, 0);
HttpClient http_client = HttpClient(gsm_client_secure_modem, FIREBASE_HOST, SSL_PORT);

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("device serial initialize");

  sim800.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("SIM800L serial initialize");

  Serial.println("Initializing modem...");
  modem.restart();
  String modemInfo = modem.getModemInfo();
  Serial.print("Modem: ");
  Serial.println(modemInfo);

  Serial.print(F("Connecting to "));
  Serial.println(apn);

  if (!modem.gprsConnect(apn, user, pass)) {
    Serial.println("GPRS connection failed");
    // You may add retry mechanism or other error handling here
    while (1); // Infinite loop to halt the program
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("GPRS Connected");
  }

  http_client.setHttpResponseTimeout(10 * 1000); // 10 seconds timeout for HTTP responses
}

void loop()
{
  // Example: Sending data to Firebase
  if (millis() - previousMillis > 10000) {
    previousMillis = millis();

    // Sample data to send
    String data = "{\"latitude\": 123.456, \"longitude\": 456.789}";

    // Construct the URL
    String url = FIREBASE_PATH + ".json?auth=" + FIREBASE_AUTH;

    // Send the data
    int statusCode = http_client.post(url, "application/json", data);
    if (statusCode == 200) {
      Serial.println("Firebase POST successful");
    }
    else {
      Serial.print("Firebase POST failed with status code: ");
      Serial.println(statusCode);
    }
  }
}

and the second one is used to read the gps and print its data on the serial monitor and this also worked successfully
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial seril_connection(5, 6);
TinyGPSPlus gps;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  seril_connection.begin(9600);
  Serial.println ("GPS START");

}

void loop() {

  while (seril_connection.available())
  {
    gps.encode(seril_connection.read());
  }
  if (gps.location.isUpdated()) {
    Serial.println("Satellite count:");
    Serial.println(gps.satellites.value());
    Serial.println("latitude:");
    Serial.println(gps.location.lat(), 6);
    Serial.println("longitude:");
    Serial.println(gps.location.lng(), 6);
    Serial.println("speed MPH:");
    Serial.println(gps.speed.mph());
    Serial.println("Altitude feet");
    Serial.println(gps.altitude.feet());
    Serial.println("");

  }

}

